# SSH port 80 "Connection refused"

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to use port 80 for SSH on my Ubuntu server. I have previously used Apache on port 80 (which worked) but now I killed it so SSH can use port 80, but it still ain't working. I can connect to SSH on port 22 but I can't connect via port 80, I only get the error "Connection refused". What should I try next?

Error-message:

```
user@server:~$ ssh -p 80 anotheruser@anotherserver
ssh: connect to host anotherserver port 80: Connection refused
```

Comment: See what additional messages you get with `-v`

Comment: Also, try just using telnet 80 to see if there is any active service on port 80.

Comment: Post output of `nc -vvv -z <server> 80`

Comment: `user@server:~$ ssh -v -p 80 anotheruser@anotherserver
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to anotherserver [anotherserver] port 80.
debug1: connect to address anotherserver port 80: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host anotherserver port 80: Connection refused
user@server:~$ telnet anotherserver 80
Trying anotherserver...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

Comment: @tommielag Is the server behind a router? firewall? Describe the network

Comment: It's behind a router, model TG799vn v2 (Technicolor)

Comment: And you're not on the same local network? If so, you need to "open" the ports on the router, since it probably does NAT.

Comment: Ports that are open: 443, 80, 8080, 22.

Comment: `user@server:~$ ssh -v -p 443 anotheruser@anotherserver
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to anotherserver [anotherserver] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1`

Comment: Stops after that. No output after: `nc -vvv -z anotherserver 80`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and change Port to 80. Then run

sudo restart ssh

And then connect:

ssh user@host -p80

Comment: Already done, still not working.

Comment: @tommielag If it's still running on 22 after a restart you might be using/editing the wrong config file.

Comment: Also try using Port 443, that is also an HTTP port

Comment: Tried using port 443, works better but still not full way.

Answer (score 2):

you need to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Change the port number or add a new line if you want to listen on both e.g.

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
Port 80
```